# how to create form with several inputs without repetition - react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a signup screen with several input boxes.

```
           <TextInput
                placeholder="email"
                value={fields.email}
                onChangeText={(value) => fieldChnageHandler('email', value)}
                style={styles.input}
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255, 0.3)"
            />
            <TextInput
                placeholder="username"
                value={fields.username}
                onChangeText={(value) => fieldChnageHandler('userName', value)}
                style={styles.input}
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255, 0.3)"
            />
            <TextInput
                placeholder="full name"
                value={fields.name}
                onChangeText={(value) => fieldChnageHandler('name', value)}
                style={styles.input}
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255, 0.3)"
            />
            <TextInput
                placeholder="password"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                value={fields.password}
                onChangeText={(value) => fieldChnageHandler('password', value)}
                style={styles.input}
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255, 0.3)"
            />
            <TextInput
                placeholder="repeat password"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                value={fields.rePassword}
                onChangeText={(value) => fieldChnageHandler('rePassword', value)}
                style={styles.input}
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255, 0.3)"
            />
```

Most of the props are same and with function to handle it component is getting out of hand becoming huge. Whah would be better way to render them without repetition.

Answer (score 1):

If all items are the same component, with different props use `.map()`. You can combine this with [Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62938602/11917764).

```js
const inputs = [
  { label: 'Username', placeholder: 'Username here' },
  { label: 'password', placeholder: 'Password here' }
]
```

```js
{inputs.map((input) => 
  <TextInput
    label={input.label}
    placeholder={input.placeholder}
  />
)}
```

Comment: yes, I tried that. But the problem with .map() is handling its onChange later.

Comment: Create your function to take a key and a value, identify the field by key and change it `(key, value) => setState({...state, [key]: value});`

Answer (score 0):

For the common props, you can do

```
const commonProps = {
  placeholderTextColor: "rgba(255,255,255, 0.3)",
  style: styles.input
  ...
}
```

And then use them like this:

```
<TextInput
  not
  common
  { ...commonProps }
/>
```